# How to add JWT token into credentials in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework-jwt

In testing, I cannot authenticate my test user. How to add JWT token into self.client.credentials.

```
def test_retrive_profile_success(self):
    """Test retriving profile for authenticated user"""
    res1 = self.client.post(TOKEN_URL, {'email':'test@greatsoft.uz', 'password':'password'})
    token = res1.data['token']
    self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token)
    res = self.client.get(ME_URL)
    self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
    self.assertEqual(res.data, {
        'email':self.user.email
    })
```

I am getting a response of 401.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need change this line

```py
self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token)
```

to this

```py
self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Bearer ' + token)
```

Comment: (For others) If it did not work Please try JWT instead of Bearer or Token

Comment: JWT worked for my case, I thinkg self.client.for_login or self.client.authenticate should do the job and then you do not need to add JWT